# Interactively checking default hyphenations

Tags: hyphenation, interaction

I'm using this programme

```
\let\\\showhyphens
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\begin{document}
```

to check default hyphenations interactively by typing

```
*\\{necessarily}
```

&c.  Is there a way to do this without having to type `\\{}`?
(Something similar perhaps to `expr.mf`.)

(And what would be the most correct place to put this under the local
`~/texmf/`?)

Answer (score 3):

You could set up the main vertical list to use the same settings as the box that `\showhyphens` uses but here I just loop and apply `\\` each time, and empty entry returns you to the `*` prompt

```
\let\\\showhyphens
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\begin{document}
\loop
\typein[\tmp]{Word:}
\\{\tmp}
\ifx\tmp\empty\else
\repeat
```

Comment: +1, but maybe you could remove the `\let\\\showhyphens`, use `\showhyphens` directly and finish with `\end{document}` for good measure? Yes, I know, I am *so conventional*. :-)

Comment: @frougon I wondered about doing that (and putting `\stop` after the loop) but I decided to return to the `*` prompt so the `\\ ` shorthand might still be needed if the OP thinks of another word to check.

Comment: Ah, okay... thanks for the explanation, then. :-)